# Using same Configuration in two different applications

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, azure-functions, console-application

I'm currently developing solution which includes two applications: Azure Function & basic Console Application.

I would like to use same Configuration file (local.settings.json, which is initialized in Azure Function) in the Console Application as well. I was wondering is this possible, and if so how can I do it?

Configuration initialization in Azure Function:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
    }

    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .SetBasePath(context.ApplicationRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("settings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    }
}
```

I would like to access that same configuration in another program which is placed under same solution (Particularly in ExampleService -class) :

```
namespace ExampleProgram
{
class Program
{
    private static ExampleService? _exampleService;
    static async Task Main()
    {
        _exampleService = new ExampleService();
        await _exampleService.Run();
    }
}

public class ExampleService
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the scenario and I got the below one as output

AFAIK, it cannot be run through `localsettings.json` , But you can run it through `AppSetting.json`  in console app
and I followed below process

1. I have created a function app and added `appsettings.json`

**AppSettings.json:**

```
    {
  "AppSettings": {

  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppDbConnection": "Server=sqlserverhost.domain.com;Database=DBName; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }, 
}
```

2. After creating function app Goto console application and right click and Goto **Add** and select **project reference** as show in the below picture

[image]

4. I have created a Console App and added below code

**Console App**
**.csproj**  File

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" Version="5.6.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="AppSettings.json">            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Program.cs:**

```
 using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;
using ConsoleApp1;

namespace AppSettingsExample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IConfigurationRoot configuration;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceCollection serviceDescriptors = new ServiceCollection();

            ConfigureServices(serviceDescriptors);
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceDescriptors.BuildServiceProvider();

            Console.WriteLine(configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbConnection"));
        }
        private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
           

            configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();    
        }        
    }
}
```

**App.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class App
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;
        private readonly ILogger<App> _logger;
    }
}
```

and I am able to get the Function app `AppSetings.json` date in Console Application

[image]